# Как в swift поменять ширину каждой кнопки в стеке?

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть стек из кнопок. Вертикальный. Я хочу что бы каждая нижняя кнопка была меньше, условно, на 5 пикселей. Как быть? Кнопка кастомная, констрейны все в false. Как обратиться к каждой кнопке по индексу в словаре?

func addButtonsToStack () {

```
    var colorLiteral: Dictionary = [UIColor: String] ()
    
    colorLiteral[.red] = "C"
    colorLiteral[.blue] = "D"
    colorLiteral[.green] = "E"
    colorLiteral[.brown] = "F"
    colorLiteral[.orange] = "G"
    colorLiteral[.black] = "A"
    colorLiteral[.purple] = "B"
    
  
    
    for (key,value) in colorLiteral {
        
        
        
        let button = CustomButton()
       
        
        button.setTitle(value, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = key
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: // вот здаесь какую формулу написать, что бы менялась ширина кнопок ).isActive = true
        mainStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
```